# Refreshing Auth Token while keep the requests running in JMeter 3.3

Tags: multithreading, authentication, jmeter, refresh, token

I have the following scenario using *Jmeter 3.3:*

I would like to run "`Get auth token`" once every 2.5 minutes and meanwhile to run `[GET]` thread group non stop.

In other words, `[GET]` is taking the auth token from the first thread group and I would like to run them in parallel and only change the token once at 2.5 min.

I tried to add a Constant Timer to the first thread but the second thread is not running until the timer passed.

How can I keep the `[GET]` running non-stop and "`Get Auth token`" only once at 2.5min?

**LE:**

`[GET]` Thread is used for load tests and should be run with ~100 active users (all using the same token)

Constant Timer was added under HTTP Sampler

```
> Get Auth token
>> [POST] Auth token
>>> HTTP Header Manager
>>> Regular Expression Extractor
>>> Response Assertion
>>> Constant Timer
```

**LE2:**
I have tried adding a Test action under the first thread group. I did not manage to make Thread 2 run without waiting after Thread's 1 delay.

Comment: When you added the constant timer, did you put it as a child of the HTTP sampler?

Comment: Yes, I did. Exactly under 'Response Assertion' under '[POST] Auth token'. The problem is that for thread 1 I have the delay applied, but while the delay is taking effect Thread 2 is on pause as well. I want thread 2 to run meanwhile.

Comment: Its working fine with me, but here is another thing that you can try, add a test action sampler just after the HTTP sampler in your first thread group and configure it to pause with the duration you want and remove the timers and try it.

Comment: No luck. I start to think it has something to do with Inter-Thread Communication. If I duplicate Thread 2 and remove the auth token obtained in Thread 1, it works fine.

Comment: Whats your if statement? Can you please add a debug sampler just before your if controller and run with the test action configuration, watch the view result tree and see if the thread is not executed at all or it isn't going into the if controller.

Comment: This is the if statement: `"${__fifoPop(access_token,gotAccessToken)}" != ""` and it is going inside IF. In the second thread I do manage to obtain auth token from the first thread group. "Bearer ${gotAccessToken}" it is working fine. But for some reason, thread 2 is waiting for thread's 1 delay.

Comment: @ararar thank you for your help. Dmitri's solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) User Manual chapter

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads**, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So I would suggest converting your `authToken` into a JMeter Property via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in `Get auth token` Thread Group and refering the value in `Get` Thread Group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) so once the `authToken` value is updated all the threads will be using the new value instead of the old one.

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. This, together with Test Action, fixed the issue.