# Jmeter token refreshing

Tags: jmeter

I find the topic [Refreshing Auth Token while keep the requests running in JMeter 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748594/refreshing-auth-token-while-keep-the-requests-running-in-jmeter-3-3). I faced with same task - token refreshing each x time and other request sending at the same time. I've seen that author has find the solution. But I would be really appreciated if you could share the logic. I  tried with global property in Jmeter, but it seems that I set one token for all users. The timer was allso added,  but I'm getting one token for sessions. Probably we have a new solution for Jmeter 5.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be the same, you just need to amend it a little bit and use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) in order to create thread (virtual user)-specific properties.

Something like:

```
${__setProperty(token_${__threadNum},variable containing the token,)}
```

will generate the following JMeter properties:

```
token_0=token for the first virtual user
token_1=token for the second virtual user
etc.
```

which can be accessed similarly using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(token_${__threadNum},)}
```

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! I have implemented my script using the following logic in one thread group:

1. Set var “Trigger” = 60 seconds (token refreshing interval, per minute);
2. Login user;
3. Get Token request; and execute actions:

   - Extract Token and save to vars;
   - Save “TokenTime” to vars (where “Login” from CSV is the name of property);
   - Calculate “TokenDiffTime” = “TimeNow- TokenTime” -> Save as property with unique name (the unique name can be the string “Login”+”TimeDiff”- where “Login” is dynamic Login from CSV and “TimeDiff” – just static string; the example of property name is “User1TimeDiff”).
4. Loop controller with logic:

   - If Controller (Is token Actual? -> check “TokenDiffTime” >=“Trigger”) -> Call Refresh Token request; Extract actual token.
   - Invoke App request; using actual token.
   - If Controller (Is token Actual? -> check “TokenDiffTime” >=“Trigger”) -> Call Refresh Token request; Extract actual token.
   - Invoke App request; using actual token.

So, such logic takes into account the response time delays and a new app request is invoking with actual token. “Trigger” is flexible value to set token refreshing interval. Hope such topic could be useful to someone.